# Accessing markLogic from another localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, marklogic

I am trying to use markLogic as a document repository and to write a client that can access it from my localhost (Apache)...

In markLogic, I have created a new REST server (8011) and I now would like to access a markLogic database from the client with a (hopefully simple) HTTP request (actually using jQuery $.ajax).
However, the CORS problem rears its ugly head(er). After researching stackoverflow I have modified the $.ajax to include the statement: "crossDomain: true," - however this is not enough.

Do I need to modify my localhost (Apache) in any way?

It may be that I need to modify the response server (markLogic localhost:8011) to: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *." ?

How to do this? It seems as though the command should be the markLogic: "xdmp:add-response-header("meta", "description")" -however, where, in what form? Is this a parameter or a pgm statement?

This appears to be common problem as I have run  across several questions of this nature - but no answers.

Answer (score 4):

Common practice is to do one of two things:

1. use a two-tier architecture, in which MarkLogic hosts the JavaScript/HTML/CSS/etc in addition to the REST endpoints that will provide your data.
2. use a three-tier architecture where your client (browser) sends its requests to the middle tier, which forwards the request on to MarkLogic.

Either approach is legitimate. You can take a look at [Samplestack](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack) for an example of the three-tier approach. Current implementation provides a Java middle tier; in the not-too-distant future there should be a Node.js middle tier option. The [slush-marklogic-node generator](https://github.com/marklogic/slush-marklogic-node) also sets up a three-tier approach, with Node.js as the middle tier (this one is less polished than Samplestack, but pretty straightforward to get going).

Answer (score 4):

Since the question mentioned apache, perhaps it's easiest to transparently reverse-proxy the MarkLogic requests through that front-end web server. As far as the browser is concerned that should look like one host and port.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html has full docs but I think it could be as simple as:

```
 ProxyPassReverse /ml8011/ http://localhost:8011/
```

Comment: There's no need to introduce a middle tier.  With a reverse proxy (from the browser's standpoint), it will look like the same origin even though there are multiple servers on the backend.  Plus you can move your static asets into the Apache proxy instead of using MarkLogic to serve them.